# How can nerves slide without tearing

Tags: neuroanatomy

While reading about an exercise called nerve glides I learned that nerves are quite inelastic. With all the nerve branches and relatively straight path how do nerves slide back and forth without stretching or snagging? My idea is they have to be located at the neutral axis (imagine your joints as beams) so that they only ever bend and never stretch. But they would have to travel directly through the center of the joint for that to be true which they don’t (except the spine more or less).

Comment: Hi and welcome. This site requires evidence of prior research (a source, link and quote). Can you please link to the site where you are getting your information? What support from reasonable sources do you have for your idea? Thanks!

Comment: Inelastic *compared to what*?

Comment: Muscles, skin, etc. Am I wrong and they are fairly elastic? I couldn’t find sources that really pinned down just how inelastic nerves are. I would think it would cause issues if it was less elastic then everything surrounding it.

Comment: Look at nerve placement in the body, most large nerves are close to or inside the bone thus in locations that don't  stretch much.